# Not reading item content from Sitecore

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, sitecore, sitecore7.2, server-error

I have a very weird problem that I encountered while a deployment of a Sitecore based website onto a server.

The idea behind all of the structure is that we have a main application (one project - basic sitecore app) and another application (second project - app developed as an Area of the first one). In this way, for the deployment of the second one, the idea would be just to copy the dll's, some specific config files and the views from the Areas folder. Also the items from Sitecore to be moved on the new instance.

Ok...I did all of these steps (to mention that on my local machine it works as expected), but on the second server it doesn't.

The thing is that I noticed that the content from sitecore is not displayed on the screen, as the connection to the database would not be made. But it is active, as I can access Sitecore directly from the login panel under the same domain.

Besides the problem presented above (with the second app not having content), there is also now a problem with the main app, throwing an error like in the attachment:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? There is nothing special in the View where the error is thrown. I am absolutely clueless about why this is happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need to fix any connection string issues before you can fully resolve all your problems. When you mentioned

> The thing is that I noticed that the content from sitecore is not
>   displayed on the screen, as the connection to the database would not
>   be made.

If you have a connection string issue, you would get a YSOD (Yellow Screen of Death) indicating a SqlServer connection string issue, so that should be quite obvious.

Regarding the error message screenshot and the odd highlighting of the NullReferenceException line; I have noticed in the past, that you can get quite misleading error messages in MVC renderings if the parent rendering encounters a NullRef error. I would check that all the required items are published as this is probably the most common cause of problems when something works in one environment but not another. You can verify if things are published by going to the Sitecore Desktop and then changing the database to "web" using the button in the bottom right corner, then browsing through the content tree in the web database.

Comment: Already did all the things you mentioned. Those were the first things that came into my mind when I noticed the problem. Items are published, connection strings are ok, as I tested them on a different environment and worked.